# How can I cancel a not yet pushed transaction in Mist?

Tags: transactions, mist, network, offline

I created a transaction while not connected to any nodes in Mist wallet and I don't want to announce it to the network anymore.

How do I withdraw this transaction with 0 confirmations? My concern is that it will be pushed to the network once I restart the wallet software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens if while off-line, you open MIST switch it to the test network, close it, go online, open MIST and fire the transaction?

I have a similar problem with an account I created that is stuck doing nothing, I delved into all the files via deep text search looking to delete that specific one. I have not followed through though, when I do and if it works, I will report back.

**edit add:**

While I wait for my MIST to sync:

1. remove and save somewhere, the corresponding keystore file for that wallet. It will UTC-- the address of the wallet. This should remove that from MIST when you open it up. Question is will it flush out any pending transactions that are written somewhere else? No wallet nothing to send. Close MIST put back the keystore file in the folder, the account will be there again, hopefully minus any pending transactions. If not
2. It is or has been written elsewhere by GET? If so you must be able to delete it direct from GET? I don't know the commands but surely someone can input if this is the case, how to remove a pending transaction from GET, if indeed it has written and saved that.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, i guess i found a solution.

You can delete `C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Roaming\Mist` and restart `Mist.exe`

It will initiate new, your wallets are still there (because keystore in `\Roaming\Ethereum\keystore\...`)